# Count number of partial matches between two columns in a table

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I am attempted to count the number of partial or complete matches between two columns in a table with some limitations:

| IA_DX | AUDIT_DX | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I21.0 | I10, I21.A1, I21.0 | 1 |
| L08.0 | L08.0 | 1 |
| D71 | D71.9 | 0 |

The limited formula I have that would give a count of 1 (for row 2 above) is:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT(K1985&"[IA_DX]")=INDIRECT(K1985&"[AUDIT_DX]")),--(INDIRECT(K1985&"[IA_DX]")<>""))`

I want to also search for strings in IA_DX in AUDIT_DX and include matches, but not if they are not 'exact' matches like in row 3. I am also using indirects for this formula because I have a drop-down list of different sheet names. TIA!

I tried various attempts to include a wildcard and tried researching the use of `SEARCH` and `ISNUMBER`

Comment: How about `=SUM(--(TEXTSPLIT([@[AUDIT_DX]],", ")=[@[IA_DX]]))`? If the result is in the same table, the table name is not important, right?

Comment: Not sure why you're using INDIRECT (at all) is it for same row? `=--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&A2&", ",", "&B2&", "))`

Comment: @P.b - From 'Sheet 1' I am referencing a drop-down list of sheet names in cell K1985 (actually a different cell but I forgot to change).

Comment: @VBasic2008 -  All the data is located on the same table though on the selected sheet.

Comment: Are there many different sheets and are they subject to change? You may not want to use volatile functions, especially not judging by the position of your cell in row 1985.